# Pass ServletResponse Headers into ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

A Spring MVC controller needs to conditionally either:

1.) forward the user to a very different URI, or
2.) return the preceding view so that the user can re-enter data in the same form

My research indicates that the redirect should be done by giving the controller method a return type of `ResponseEntity`.  **How can I convert the `HttpHeaders` from the `HttpServletResponse` that was passed into the controller method into the new `ResponseEntity` that gets created in the controller?**

There is no `HttpServletResponse.getHeaders()` method, and there must be a more elegant method than (in pseudocode):

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
for(String headerName : HttpServletResponse.getHeaderNames()) {
    responseHeaders.add(httpServletResponse.getHeader(headerName)); 
    or 
    responseHeaders.add(httpServletResponse.getHeaders(headerName));.  
}
add responseHeaders to new ResponseEntity;
```

This is confounded a bit by the additional requirement that the controller should alternatively be able to return the previous FreeMarker view from which the user called the controller, if the user did not provide the correct information in the preceding FreeMarker view's form.

**Here is the code I have do far.  What specific changes need to be made to it?**

```
@RequestMapping("/handle")
public ResponseEntity<?> handle( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = resp.getHeaders();//THIS IS NOT IN THE API
    responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
    boolean locationRedirect = true;
    // Add some logic to determine whether to 1.) forward the user or 2.) return the previous view so they can re-enter information
    if(locationRedirect){
        try {
            URI location = new URI("some_uri_to_send_user_to_if_they_entered_correct_value_in_form");
            responseHeaders.setLocation(location);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } else{// send the user back to the freeMarker view that would otherwise be at 'return "viewName";'
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("viewName", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```